# How do I get SpotPass clothing?

Tags: tomodachi-life

I've seen a lot of QR codes that have SpotPass clothing, how do you actually get them? I know it's Spotpass, but what exactly do you do?

Answer (score 2):

Choose import wear, use StreetPass at least 1 time, or received goods from SpotPass

> The Import Wear store is the only place to buy clothing and hats that are exported from the player's island, imported from other player's islands by via StreetPass, or imported from via SpotPass, which is usually from Nintendo Island
>
> There are a total of 24 Spotpass items, each given out on one half of a month over Spotpass. When given out initially, only a few colors will be available (and in a rare case unique to Spotpass items, missing colors are not shown as dotted lines in the shop). When that item gets featured again the following year, all the remaining colors of that outfit will be added, requiring two full years of playing Tomodachi Life to unlock all of these outfits and their respective colors.
>
> The roster of Spotpass items differs from region to region, with some items that would be treated as normal clothing that could be bought from the Clothing Shop or Hats in one region would become Spotpass-exclusive in another.

[Tomodachi life wiki](http://tomodachi.wikia.com/wiki/Import_Wear)